# Netbeans python Pyserial import not found

Tags: python, import, pyserial, netbeans-8

I installed "plugged in" Python as a plug in into Netbeans using from [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/python_in_netbeans_ide_8). I was using Eclipse, and even though it was a little wonky, it could at least find Pyserial. Now, when I try to run a project (which worked fine in Eclipse), I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Prog\PythonCurrent\RadioDB\src\radiodb.py", line 8, in <module>
    import serial
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pyserial-2.7-py3.4-win32.egg\serial\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pyserial-2.7-py3.4-win32.egg\serial\serialwin32.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2222, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2164, in _find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1940, in find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1916, in _get_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1897, in _legacy_get_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 863, in spec_from_loader
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 904, in spec_from_file_location
  File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pyserial-2.7-py3.4-win32.egg\serial\win32.py", line 196
    MAXDWORD = 4294967295L # Variable c_uint
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I don't understand why. My `python34\Lib` directory contains `searial`'s stuff, and in `python34\Lib\site-packages` I have the same folder in addition to pyserial's egg and egg-info files. Do I need to specify where these are in Netbeans or copy some folders to Netbeans?

## SOLUTION:

Thanks @[Padraic Cunningham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2141635/padraic-cunningham)

I just like to make sure that the solution is clear for anyone because I have been lost before (like anyone at first).

Sooo, the solution is `use pip3 install pyserial to install for python3`...

I like to make cmd doskey macros, so I'll probably do that, but the easiest thing to install something with "pip3" is go to cmd.exe/terminal and then go to python home directory, then cd to `scripts`; type `pip3.exe install pyserial` or whatever you are installing (you can use `pip3.4.exe...` if you have it) and voila... easiest thing in the world if you know about it.

Comment: Python3 removed the 'L' suffixes from long integer literals. That would work on Python2, though.

Comment: The `pyserial` module you have seems to be the 2.x version, you should either install the 3.x version or just use Python2. Does Netbeans allow you to choose between Python2 and Python3? If it does, try selecting Python2.

Comment: Hm. That stinks! Why would they put that in pyserial-2.7-**py3.4** then?

Comment: You're right, then you must be using Python2 + pyserial (for 3.x). If Netbeans allows it, try creating a Python3 project.

Comment: use `pip3 install pyserial` to install for python3

Comment: Thanks! I'll user pip3(.4) from now on. I was just using python34\python.exe setup.py install after download.

Comment: No worries, use pip for python2 and pip3.4 for python3 packages, it is the easiest way to install packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@PadraicCunningham

---

use `pip3 install pyserial` to install almost major packages.

Answer (score -1):

Pyserial isn't updated to Python 3 yet, it only works in Python 2. So change your interpreter to Python 2.7.

Comment: However, [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyserial) it's said that Python3 is supported.

Comment: It seems like it is updated to python3 (not entirely sure), but there are eggs for py3.4... If I *did* switch to 2.7 python interpreter, would I have to write in that style (i.e. `print 'hi'` isntead of `print('hi')`?

Comment: @Dylan if you're used to Python3 there is a `__future__` module (in the 2.x). Just do `from __future__ import print_function` and you're good to go.